# Update control and refresh form by call from class to main form

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to update text box while doing something in other class. Let me put my code :

### Form1.cs

```
namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        CalledClass call = new CalledClass();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            call.Call_UpdateBox();
        }

        public void UpdateBox()
        {
            textBox1.Text = "hello";
        }
    }
}
```

### CalledClass.cs

```
namespace TestApp
{
    class CalledClass
    {
     public void Call_UpdateBox()
        {
            Form1 mainform = new Form1();

            //do looping for doing some tasks here and update textbox every time
            mainform.UpdateBox();
        }
    }
}
```

The Call_UpdateBox function in CalledClass is called when the button on main form is clicked, where I have to do some looping and in between update the textbox in the main form. Though textbox gets updated if i see its value in debug mode, but it reamins blank on main form. Please suggest. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're declaring a new instance of `Form1`, not referencing the one that already exists.  You should:

```
namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        CalledClass call = new CalledClass();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            call.Call_UpdateBox(this);
        }

        public void UpdateBox()
        {
            textBox1.Text = "hello";
        }
    }
}
namespace TestApp
{
    class CalledClass
    {
     public void Call_UpdateBox(Form1 Sender)
        {
            //do looping for doing some tasks here and update textbox every time
            sender.UpdateBox();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx Don, its atleast showing something, but like i update textbox with two different values for every iteration in loop, it only shows fixed second value. Doesn't kind of updates live.

Comment: What is happening during the loop, where the TextBox is being updated?  Is it really happening slowly enough that you could even see it occur?  I would expect it to be so quick that the TextBox refresh would be overwhelmed and it would _appear_ as if the last value was the _only_ value, when in fact, it's just too fast to perceive.  If you think that that is incorrect, please explain how and why.

Comment: yeah its happening so fast.....that textbox can show last value only, i think to see different values i have to add extra delay in between

Comment: You could force the issue with something like `Thread.Sleep(1000)` if you wanted to, but that seems clunky.  Perhaps you should re-think what you are doing with that display.  What about a textual list of "what happened"?  Like a log or something (on-screen or not).

Comment: Hi @DonBoitnott, I'm trying to do something similar to this in Visual C++. I have a main form class: MyForm which contains any number of instances of another class: MyItem. My objective is to access MyForm's method from MyItem's method definitions. How do I avoid a circular include if I were to follow this answer?

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new form instance, and you don't even show it. So you're not calling `UpdateBox()` on the good object instance.

Instead, re-use your current instance of your `mainForm`. For example:

```
public void Call_UpdateBox(Form1 targetForm)
{
    targetForm.UpdateBox();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    call.Call_UpdateBox(this);
}
```

Comment: Thx Ken, same as above, this is useful, atleast it shows something but cannot update textbox with two different values for each iteration. shows only fixed second value.

Answer (score 2):

The simpliest way

```
namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        CalledClass call = new CalledClass();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            call.FormH = this;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            call.Call_UpdateBox();
        }

        public void UpdateBox()
        {
            textBox1.Text = "hello";
        }
    }
}

namespace TestApp
{
    class CalledClass
    {
        public static Form1 FormH;

        public void Call_UpdateBox()
        {
            //do looping for doing some tasks here and update textbox every time
            FormH.UpdateBox();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx Peu...but im not getting FormH in my calledclass call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Threads` but a simpler way, since you are in WindowsForms is to use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx),

Your Form1 would be some like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BackgroundWorker _bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    CalledClass call = new CalledClass();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        bw_ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bw.IsBusy != true)
        {
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        call.Call_UpdateBox();
    }

    private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "hello";

        // Here you can access some progress property from CalledClass in order to monitor and inform progress
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx Renan, I tried it, but it didnt appear to work for me, as in calledclass when i define new instance of form1 , it throws stackoverflow error.

Comment: Try to remove `Form1 mainform = new Form1();` from CalledClass, in they way I put, you won't need it anymore

Comment: The way I posted tho "handles" the call is the BackgroundWorker, in the events _DoWork and _ProgressChanged. It is intended for long running operation, what appears to be the case in you loop inside CalledClass